# Collision detection between a polygon and a circle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was wondering how collision detection worked in pygame, between a polygon and a circle, for a football game. What I am trying to do, is make a ball move in the direction that the car hit it in. Please can somebody fix my code, I'm very stuck!!. If you run the following code, two cars will move, but nothing will happen if they hit the ball, and no error messages(Line 26 for my attempt at making it work). For starters, I just want it to print("Hello"). I would really appreciate if someone could help.
Thank You

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1150, 800))

redx = 50
redy = 30
bluex = 100
bluey = 30 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  
BLUECAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((bluex, bluey), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, (0, 0, 255), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
bluecar = BLUECAR_ORIGINAL

REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((redx,redy), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 0), (50, 10), (50, 20), (0, 30)])
redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL



def paddle_hit():
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(ball, bluerect):
        print("HI")
    elif pygame.sprite.collide_rect(ball, redrect):
        print("hello")









pos = Vector2(70, 70)  
vel = Vector2(7, 0)

poss = Vector2(70,70)
vell = Vector2(7,0)

redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)
redangle = 0  

bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=pos)
blueangle = 0

ballx = 575
bally = 400




run = True
while run:
    ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [0,0,0],[ballx,bally],30)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False






    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)

        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)


    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        blueangle += 5
        vell.rotate_ip(-5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=pos)
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        blueangle -= 5
        vell.rotate_ip(5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=poss)




    pos += vel
    redrect.center = pos  

    poss += vell
    bluerect.center = poss

    bgImg = pygame.image.load("Football_pitch.png")
    screen.blit(bgImg, (0,0))

    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)

    screen.blit(bluecar, bluerect)






    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You probably need to use pygame.sprite.collide_mask [link](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

Comment: You never call `paddle_hit`. And even if you would, it wouldn't work because `collide_rect` expects sprites as arguments.

Comment: I've tried that from several YouTube videos and Stack Overflow pages (but didn't succeed), can you tell me how to do it with my code?

Comment: Sorry, PaddleHit was meant to be called ball hit

Comment: Ok, didn't notice that thanks

Comment: So do you know how mask works? I've called paddle_hit, but it doesn't work still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use masks for the collision detection and set the velocity of the ball to the velocity of the colliding player.

Create [`pygame.mask.Mask`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask)  objects (with [`pygame.mask.from_surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface)) for the ball, the red and the blue car (when the cars rotate, you have to create new masks).

In the `while` loop, calculate the offsets between the cars and the ball and then call the [`overlap`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) method to see if they overlap. It returns the point of collision if the masks collide, otherwise `None`. So if `overlap` doesn't return `None`, you can set the velocity of the ball to the velocity of the player and it will move in the same direction. Scale the velocity vector to kick the ball.

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1150, 800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Images.
BG_IMG = pygame.Surface((1150, 800))
BG_IMG.fill((30, 120, 30))
BLUECAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, (0, 0, 255), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
bluecar = BLUECAR_ORIGINAL
REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 0), (50, 10), (50, 20), (0, 30)])
redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL

BALL = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(BALL, [250,250,250], [15, 15], 15)
# Ball variables.
ball_pos = Vector2(575, 400)
ballrect = BALL.get_rect(center=ball_pos)
ball_vel = Vector2(0, 0)
# Car variables.
pos_red = Vector2(470, 370)
vel_red = Vector2(3, 0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
redangle = 0
pos_blue = Vector2(70,70)
vel_blue = Vector2(3,0)
bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
blueangle = 0
# Masks.
mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)
mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
mask_ball = pygame.mask.from_surface(BALL)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        # We need a new mask after the rotation.
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        blueangle += 5
        vel_blue.rotate_ip(-5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=bluerect.center)
        mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        blueangle -= 5
        vel_blue.rotate_ip(5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=bluerect.center)
        mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)

    # Move the cars.
    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red
    pos_blue += vel_blue
    bluerect.center = pos_blue
    # Move the ball.
    ball_vel *= .99  # Friction.
    ball_pos += ball_vel
    ballrect.center = ball_pos

    # Red car collision.
    # We need the offset between the redrect and the ballrect.
    offset_red = redrect[0] - ballrect[0], redrect[1] - ballrect[1]
    # Pass the offset to the `overlap` method. If the masks collide,
    # overlap will return a single point, otherwise `None`.
    overlap_red = mask_ball.overlap(mask_red, offset_red)
    # Blue car collision.
    offset_blue = bluerect[0] - ballrect[0], bluerect[1] - ballrect[1]
    overlap_blue = mask_ball.overlap(mask_blue, offset_blue)

    if overlap_red and overlap_blue:  # Both collide with the ball.
        # Not sure what should happen here.
        ball_vel = vel_red + vel_blue * 1.4
    elif overlap_red:  # Red collides with the ball.
        ball_vel = Vector2(vel_red) * 1.4
    elif overlap_blue:  # Blue collides with the ball.
        ball_vel = Vector2(vel_blue) * 1.4

    # Drawing.
    screen.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(BALL, ballrect)
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    screen.blit(bluecar, bluerect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, was a perfect answer, very helpful!! You also helped me in the movement of the cars so thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

I've written a new python lib for collision detection between concave/convex polygons, and circles. It works very well, and is pretty efficient. It's pretty simple to use, and there are examples in the repository, as well as documentation.

https://github.com/QwekoDev/collision